# How to make a Firebird SP, get lines from some dynamic TABLES?

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird

My tables have some inner pre-fix that users must not know.
So I made a SP like this to retrieve lines.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_Test  
 ( inStation varchar(10) )  
RETURNS  
 ( ServiceName varchar(20) )  
AS    
DECLARE VARIABLE StationTable varchar(20);  
BEGIN   
  StationTable = 'TSTATION_' || Upper(Trim(inStation));  

  SELECT StationTable.ServiceName  
  FROM StationTable  
  INTO :ServiceName;  
  suspend;  

END^
```

And I got a fail message like this

> SQL error code = -204
>   Table unknown
>   STATIONTABLE

My fbclient.dll version is 2.1.2.18118.
My test enviroment is Flamerobin 0.9.2.1851.

Any idea to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to use execute block :

```
execute block (inStation varchar(10) = ?)
returns (ServiceName = varchar(20))
as
DECLARE variable SQL Varchar(300);
DECLARE VARIABLE StationTable varchar(20);
begin
    StationTable = 'TSTATION_' || Upper(Trim(inStation)); 
    SQL := 'SELECT ' || StationTable ||'.ServiceName FROM ' || StationTable || ' INTO :ServiceName;';
    execute STATEMENT sql;
    SUSPEND;
end
```

check [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-execblock.html)

Comment: I've tried your code.  
Still end up with an error message 
 
>Token unknown - line 10, column 5  
>execute

Comment: I forget ; a the end of line 9. May be it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your tips, @Hugues Van Landeghem. I've made it work using the two keywords `EXECUTE STATEMENT`. Here is my SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_Test ( inStation varchar(10) )
RETURNS ( ServiceName varchar(20) )
AS
    DECLARE VARIABLE StationTable varchar(20);  
BEGIN   
    StationTable = 'TSTATION_' || Upper(Trim(inStation));  
    EXECUTE STATEMENT 'SELECT ServiceName FROM ' || StationTable INTO :ServiceName;
    SUSPEND;  
END^
```